# Putty SSH Session closes immediately after login with latest ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Update

Tags: 18.04, putty

The session disconnects after about 5 seconds with putty. If I type the password really fast I can get the welcome screen before the connection is dropped. I do weekly updates so this is something pretty recent. I noticed with the new update it says "Using keyboard-interactive authentication". So something got changed and now my server is effectively bricked. Ideas??

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -v` (verbose) option to see if any clues are provided?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I asked prematurely. Not sure what was going on after the update, but CPU and network usage spiked. After it stopped I rebooted a second time and now it's working correctly.